# How to read 2nd element of list of xml items returned in response using ExtractVariables policy in apigee?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, apigee

I am receiving an XML payload response target system that follows the following structure...

```
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <title/>
   <id>7c818dcd-d66a-4273-b043-ff468b956d1b</id>
   <link rel="self" href="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu1/Patient?address=usa"/>
   <link rel="next" href="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu1?_getpages=943fd84d-1f93-4c97-8bba-534e944e74cf&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true"/>
   <link rel="fhir-base" href="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu1"/>
  </feed>
```

and am trying to use an Extract Variables policy to obtain the value of the href attribute of `<link>` tag where attribute rel="next".

Following is the Extract variable policy i have written that extracts value of attribute href of first `<link>` tag.

```
<ExtractVariables name="ReadLinkURLs">
       <Source>response</Source>
       <XMLPayload>
        <Namespaces>
            <Namespace prefix="patient">http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</Namespace>
        </Namespaces>
        <Variable name="href" type="string">
            <XPath>/patient:feed/patient:link/@href</XPath>
        </Variable>
    </XMLPayload>
       <VariablePrefix>pagingpatient</VariablePrefix>
    </ExtractVariables>
```

The variable 'href' is set to the string "http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu1/Patient?address=usa", i.e the first value. Can you please suggest the changes i have to make to read the `href` attribute value of that `<link>` element in which `rel="next"`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about [apigee](/questions/tagged/apigee), but the XPath predicate expression to restrict `<link>` elements to only those having `rel` attribute value equals `"next"` is `[@rel='next']`. So, your entire XPath expression should look about like this :

```
<XPath>/patient:feed/patient:link[@rel='next']/@href</XPath>
```

Comment: can you please provide the XPath to read value attribute of 'url' in which value of 'relation' is self. Following is xml data:

Comment: <Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
   <id value="6119160a75ba4b0"/>
   <type value="searchset"/>
   <base value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2"/>
   <total value="535"/>
   <link>
      <relation value="self"/>
      <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2/Patient?_format=xml"/>
   </link>
   <link>
      <relation value="next"/>
      <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=0da483a1-21a8-4445-89f7-5bf0be13599e&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true"/>
   </link>

Comment: @OnkaarSingh please, post a new question for that, elaborate more and provide the expected output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833951/how-to-read-specific-elements-from-xml-data. Please respond here