# How to read specific elements from xml data?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The following is my response data:

```
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
   <id value="ffd821ee-f4d0-43fc-8eb1-df1d9bd63340"/>
   <meta>
      <lastUpdated value="2015-08-05T09:14:57.242-04:00"/>
   </meta>
   <type value="searchset"/>
   <base value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2"/>
   <total value="535"/>
   <link>
      <relation value="self"/>
      <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2/Patient?_format=xml"/>
   </link>
   <link>
      <relation value="next"/>
      <url value="http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=0bad92c1-cfe3-4a23-bd20-e24e854c16da&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true"/>
   </link>
</Bundle>
```

I need to read `value` attribute of that `<link><url>` tag in which `value` attribute of `<relation>` is `next`.

So, my expected output is `http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=0bad92c1-cfe3-4a23-bd20-e24e854c16da&amp;_getpagesoffset=10&amp;_count=10&amp;_format=xml&amp;_pretty=true`.

What will be the XPath expression for reading this?

Comment: based on [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717179/how-to-read-2nd-element-of-list-of-xml-items-returned-in-response-using-extractv), you might be looking for this kind of XPath : `/fhi:Bundle/fhi:link[fhi:relation/@value = 'next']/fhi:url/@value`, as also mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the tool or library you use to evaluate XPath expressions. If default namespaces declared on the outermost element are automatically made available to the XPath engine or ignored, the following will do:

```
string(/Bundle/link[relation/@value = 'next']/url/@value)
```

If this is not the case you need to register this namespace URI together with a prefix (specific to the tool or library) and then use the prefix in the XPath expression:

```
string(/fhi:Bundle/fhi:link[fhi:relation/@value = 'next']/fhi:url/@value)
```

Since you tagged this question with XSLT, perhaps you are using XPath within XSLT? Then declare this namespace on the `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fhi="http://hl7.org/fhir">
```

Alternatively, to ignore namespaces alltogether (not recommended), use

```
string(/*[local-name() = 'Bundle']/*[local-name() = 'link'][*[local-name() = 'relation']/@value = 'next']/*[local-name() = 'url']/@value)
```

In all cases, the result will be

```
http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2?_getpages=0bad92c1-cfe3-4a23-bd20-e24e854c16da&_getpagesoffset=10&_count=10&_format=xml&_pretty=true
```